# Como fazer layouts para diferentes resoluções de dispositivos?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

Bom galera, gostaria de saber como eu faço para criar layouts para diferentes tamanhos de tela (small, normal, large ou xlarge) no mesmo projeto no Android Studio? Eu faço os layouts no mesmo diretório: "layout" ou tenho que criar outro? O app escolhe o layout adequado para cada dispositivo automaticamente ou deve ser programado?

Desde já agradeço!

Comment: Utilize o PercentLayout e ConstraintLayout e você não precisará mais fazer múltiplos layouts, apenas 2. 1 para dispositivos normais e outro para tablets, mas só se caso você quiser layouts diferentes em tablets. ;)

Comment: @itscorey pensei exatamente assim, um para dispositivos normais e outro para tablets (large), e gostaria saber como eu posso fazer isso, pois eu já tenho um código para um normal, mas preciso fazer  para tablets, ou seja preciso  criar um novo layout para todos né?

Comment: Acredito que sim. Eu já vi alguns desenvolvedores criando APKs separadas para tablets, mas reaproveitando o código. Acredito que seja uma boa abordagem, mas só alguém com mais experiência para te responder.